# Batch download a bunch of files, limiting the download size to 100 KB

Tags: google-chrome, browser, download

I have lots of URLs of large files and plan to open them by Bulk URL Opener. It automatically starts downloading once URL is opened, I need it to pause or stop once 100 KB have been downloaded.

Is there anyway I can automate it, I can pause once I see 100 KB but manually doing it for 1000s of URL is hectic.

Note that many solution I tried involves downloading a complete file and then returning only first 100 KB. This is not what I want.

PS: I have already tried cUrl range header solution and it doesn't work probably because server don't support it.

Thanks [gronostaj](https://superuser.com/users/194694/gronostaj) for simplifying my problem and suggesting an edit.

Comment: Thank @gronostaj, I have edited it now.

Comment: Just a comment, but I might be skeptical there is an automated solution to this (as presented) unless perhaps you make your own Chrome extension to somehow stop the data at the desired values.